# Dynamic formName in redux form not working

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-form

i want to create multiple redux forms with dynamic name according to a variable. I have this code:

```
import { reduxForm, Field, change } from 'redux-form/immutable';

const CardControlActiveSettingStripeComponent = ({ cards, openCardControlStripeCallback, handleSubmit }) => (
  <div className="inner pBottom">
    {cards.map(card => (
      <form
        form={`cardControl_${card.cardNumber}`}
        key={`cardControl_${card.cardNumber}`}
        onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      >
        <Field
          id="atmLimit"
          name="atmLimit"
          component={InputCheckBoxField}
        />
      </form>
    ))}
  </div>
);

const CardControlActiveSettingStripeForm = reduxForm({})(CardControlActiveSettingStripeComponent);
```

When this is rendered and i click on the checkboxes not a single redux form is mounted to ther state

If i remove the form attribute from the form and i add a name in the redux form

```
import { reduxForm, Field, change } from 'redux-form/immutable';

        const CardControlActiveSettingStripeComponent = ({ cards, openCardControlStripeCallback, handleSubmit }) => (
      <div className="inner pBottom">
        {cards.map(card => (
          <form
            key={`cardControl_${card.cardNumber}`}
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
          >
            <Field
              id="atmLimit"
              name="atmLimit"
              component={InputCheckBoxField}
            />
          </form>
        ))}
      </div>
    );

const CardControlActiveSettingStripeForm = reduxForm({ form: 'a form'})(CardControlActiveSettingStripeComponent);


the redux form is mounted successfully in the state. But that's not what I wanted since I want to create multiple redux forms with different form names. What am I missing?
```